# URL Shortcut in Web Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ftp, directory

I'm looking for a way to upload a special type of file to a web directory.  The file will be indexed with all the other files, but when clicked, will take the user to a different web address.

Here's an example:

A directory lists three files:

- earth.png
- mars.png
- NASA.url

The .url file (the extension doesn't matter - just an example) should lead the user to NASA's website.

Think of a Windows shortcut.  Shortcut files are listed alongside "real" files in a folder; however, when they're opened, they lead to a different location entirely.

Of course, I could create a simple page with links, but I'm asking if this is possible to do using the server's indexing functionality.

If there was an issue with the clarity of this question, I apologize.  Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: I don't think there's an *easy* way to do this using Apache's built-in functionality. You *could* edit a `.htaccess` file to add a `Redirect` statement for every such file but automating that would be hard. A custom-built solution in a scripting language like PHP might be the way to go.

Comment: I'd like to avoid .htaccess edits.  At that point, I might as well just create an index file.  I suppose I'm looking for some extension or file content that Apache would recognize and handle appropriately.  Creating a PHP script, however, might be the way to go.  I could look for `.url` extensions and create links based on the file contents.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing (It would have to work like `.lnk` in Windows) but then, a .php file containing `<?php header("location: http://newlocation.com"); ?>` would have a very similar effect

Comment: Related question on Pro Webmasters with working (`.htaccess` / PHP) solution: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/make-apache-issue-redirects-for-windows-url-shortcuts-in-directory-listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that creating a custom indexing script is the best (and perhaps, only) way to do this.